# How to map relation between one table and third table proxed by second table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's have 3 tables A, B, C and relations between them.

A is many to one with B

B is one to many with C

How to write relation in sqlalchemy to have access to C from A, like: A.C[0].some_column

Comment: You mean a many-to-many relationship? http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example

A is many to one with B

B is one to many with C

So finally

A is many to many C is the last relationship if you want to access the C from A.

You have to create the [relationship](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/internals.html?highlight=relationship#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty) in each model to access directly.

For example

```
A.x is relationship with B
B.y is relationship with C
```

then you can access by A.x.y which will return you the list.

To access like A.x you can use [secondaryjoin](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=secondaryjoin#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship) you can give query which will be access direct C from A.

For example

```
Class A:

    p = relationship(C,
             primaryjoin=A.x==B.y,
             secondaryjoin=B.y==C.z
             )
```

This might be work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution. BTW: Is there any option to avoid '.x' proxy and got direct access, like A.C?